# VLOOKUP with never return same value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need some help with Excel's **VLOOKUP** function.

I have two worksheets.

The first one contains running numbers with item codes and a column for batch numbers.

It looks like this

```
A   B        C      D        E          F
0   0   05-40112R1  0   2966115100050   1
0   0   05-40112R1  1   2966115100050   1
0   0   05-40112R1  2   2966115100050   1
0   0   05-40112R1  3   2966115100050   1
0   0   05-40112R1  4   2966115100050   1
```

The second sheet contains the batch number with the item codes.

It looks like this

```
     A           B
05-40112R1  2966115100050
05-40112R1  2966115100051
05-40112R1  2966115100052
05-40112R1  2966115100053
05-40112R1  2966115100054
```

When I use **VLOOKUP** it gives me the same value for column E on the first sheet.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,'SHEET 2'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

How can I get it to only use the value once and then go on to the next value.

So the first table looks like this:

```
A   B        C      D        E          F
0   0   05-40112R1  0   2966115100050   1
0   0   05-40112R1  1   2966115100051   1
0   0   05-40112R1  2   2966115100052   1
0   0   05-40112R1  3   2966115100053   1
0   0   05-40112R1  4   2966115100054   1
```

I have a lot of data like this and copying and pasting is just take too long.

Comment: You had better show us what your VLOOKUP formula looks like

Comment: The current VLOOKUP formula looks like this =VLOOKUP(C1,'SHEET 2'!A:B,2,FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet1!E1 as a standard formula,

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(Sheet2!B$1:INDEX(Sheet2!B:B, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet2!B:B)))/(Sheet2!A:A=C1), COUNTIF(C$1:C1, C1)))
```

[image: First_Second_Third_fourth]

That assumes that Sheet2!B:B are real numbers.